# How can i add a background image for UIWebView?

Tags: ios, xcode, uiwebview, background, uiimage

How can i add a background image for UIWebView as a texture ?
I use following code but its not working?

```
 _webView.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"light.jpg"]];
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the solution

Add this line to viewDidload methode

```
 [_webView setOpaque:NO];
```

Add this line to your IBAction methode

```
_webView.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"light.jpg"]];
```

Answer (score 1):

use below code

```
[_webView loadHTMLString:string baseURL:nil];
[_webView setOpaque:NO];
_webView.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"light.jpg"]];
```

try this you will be succeed

Comment: its working under  "viewdidload "  but not working under ibaction why??

Comment: because when load method called webview set opaque = yes automatically, so

Comment: i got solution ,please check my answer

Comment: can u change the font color in webview?

Comment: you have to change font color in your html string or response

Comment: yes,if i have html file with  string "hello world" in blue font color  when it open in webview it have to show in black color with  green background??

Comment: you have to set color in html like <body text="#FFFFFF"> where FFFFFF is for white color

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27075/discussion-between-naveen-and-pratik)